# 3D modelling on an Android Project in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, monogame

I've got an existing solution in Xamarin for an app that I'm working on. However I need to do some 3D rendering as part of it.

I've looked at MonoGame however I can't see any way to directly import it as another activity so that I can easily switch to it using the standard Android API.

Is there another library which would be easier to work with as I don't have any experience with 3D modelling apart from messing around with Unity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have to do to get it working is to add the MonoGame Framework to the packages folder.

Just right click and then click on the monoGame package in the wizard.

You may also need to add the tool from the `add-in manager` in the `Tools` dropdown.